# How is deviceId determined for JSS pages

Tags: jss

I'm looking at a JSS page in connected mode. I log the route to the console and note that there is a property, `deviceId`, which matches the device called `Default`.

There are multiple devices in this project. There is the out-of-the-box `Print` device. I created a device called Googlebot which has the user agent of the Googlebot.

I do not know how to get `deviceId` to resolve to a device other than Default.

For example, `Print` is supposedly determined by a query parameter. Append the query parameter, `deviceId` is still `Default`. Spoof user agent, `deviceId` still default, not Googlebot.

What is the algorithm for determining `deviceId` on JSS pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore layout device can be specified via the standard `sc_device` querystring parameter. In connected mode, headless mode, or api-only mode, you would need to add that parameter to Layout Service requests. In integrated mode, the parameter can be added to Sitecore route requests.

Whether requesting data from Layout Service or browsing in integrated mode, the standard Sitecore device detection and resolution processes are used - JSS doesn't do anything custom.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question, but might help someone.

Instead of trying to use a Device, we wrote a short Layout Service extender to add a flag to the Sitecore Context. We found the process easier to reason about, and imagine others might as well.